# Value -like implementation of copy constructor and assignment operator

Tags: c++

Some month ago I asked a question about copy constructor and assignment operator but I didn't really solve it, and now I'm stuck again with the same problem.
I have to implement copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor of a class which contains a pointer, and the implementation must be value-like, i.e. different objects must not point to the same variable.
Suppose I have this code:

```
class A{};
class B{
A* item;
int c;
public: 
B(const A& a, int c_): item(new A(a)), c(c_){};
B(const B& b) //copy constructor
B& operator=(const B & b); //assignment operator
~B(); //destructor
}
```

Now, in a lot of examples I have , the right way to code those elements is:

```
// copy constructor
B::B(const B& b){
    item = new A(*(b.item));
    c=b.c;
}
```

Here is the first problem, the qeustion is why I need to create a new A object, instead of just assigning the value pointed by b.item to (*this).item. Last time I was told that assigning or deferencing an uninitialized pointer may cause strange behaviours.

```
// assignment operator

B::operator=(const B& b){
    if(this != &b){
        c=b.c;
        delete item;
        item = new A (*(b.item));
}
}
```

I may understand the need for the new operator for the copy constructor, bu why would I ever delete item
and reallocate another A object, instead of just copying the value pointed by b.item in this->item? Whenever the code will use the assignment operator, the pointer inside A will be initialized, so there is not the problem of assigning to an uninitialized pointer anymore, so why should I follow this procedure?

Comment: "*the qeustion is why I need to create a new A object*" But... that's what you *wanted*. You said so right here: "the implementation must be value-like, i.e. different objects must not point to the same variable". How else could that possibly happen?

Comment: If your question is *solely* about the assginment operator, then you should remove the text talking about the copy constructor.

Comment: In the assignment operator I could do:
*item = *(b.item);
instead of:
delete item;
item = new A(*(b.item));

Comment: Well, I would like to have a confirm about the copy constructor, if what I understood is right, and an answer about the assignment operator.

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you want to "confirm about the copy constructor". As previously stated, your design clearly seems to require that, so what do you need to confirm?

Comment: @Peanojr What if `item` would be `nullptr`?

Comment: @Nicolas Bolas Can I do this : *item = *(b.item); instead of: item = new A(*(b.item));  inside the copy constuctor? If not why?

Comment: @Rhathin The item you're passing or the item you're paassing to?

Comment: @Peanojr: "*Can I do this : *item = *(b.item); instead of: item = new A(*(b.item)); inside the copy constuctor?*" You don't seem to be aware that you're asking if you can can take a pointer that doesn't point to anything and dereference it. Because that's what that code would be doing. It is fundamentally no different than writing `A *item; *item = <whatever>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an object `b1`, and you create a copy `b2` like this:

```
B b1;
B b2(b1);
```

then you must create a new `A` object for `b2.item` to refer to, otherwise they will refer to the same item: hence you need the `new A` in the copy constructor of `B`.

Now consider what happens under assignment:

```
B b1;
B b2;
b2=b1;
```

In this case, the default copy assignment operator will also do the wrong thing: it will copy the `item` pointer from `b1` to `b2`, so now `b1` and `b2` will point to the same `A`. Therefore you need to write a copy assignment operator.

Since each `B` owns its own `A`, you have two choices: either destroy and recreate the `A` object, as per your example copy assignment operator, or assign the wrapped object directly:

```
B& B::operator=(B const& other){  // delete and recreate
  if(&other!=this){
    c=other.c;
    delete item;
    item=new A(*other.item);
  }
  return *this;
}

B& B::operator=(B const& other){  // assign the item
  if(&other!=this){
    c=other.c;
    *item=*other.item;
  }
  return *this;
}
```

Which is best depends on the type of `A`, and its general behaviour. e.g. if `A` cannot be assigned then you must delete and recreate, whereas if it can be assigned then you may wish to do that.